# Python - how to web scrape text with location within given page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to get "**Katowice, Brynów-Zgrzebnioka, Brynów**" from the url given in the code below

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as Open
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3"}
my_url = "https://www.otodom.pl/oferta/narozne-2-pokoje-nowa-inwestycja-0-ID43FH9.html"
req = Request(url=my_url, headers=headers) 
html = Open(req).read() 

page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")

print(page_soup.find("a", {"href":"#map"}).text)
```

So far I can get to

```
.css-14dmk7z-Le{margin-right:2px;width:15px;height:15px;padding-bottom:2px;color:#ff7200;}.css-1g0gx4e-Le{vertical-align:middle;fill:currentColor;margin-right:2px;width:15px;height:15px;padding-bottom:2px;color:#ff7200;}Katowice, Brynów-Zgrzebnioka, Brynów
```

I am not sure how to proceed further, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO.

Below a piece of code (you were just one `split` from your goal!) that returns the string you are looking for. Basically, I just split the long string that you already returned on the "}" element, and took the remaining part.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as Open
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3"}
my_url = "https://www.otodom.pl/oferta/narozne-2-pokoje-nowa-inwestycja-0-ID43FH9.html"
req = Request(url=my_url, headers=headers) 
html = Open(req).read() 

page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")

maptag = page_soup.find("a", {"href":"#map"}).text
print(maptag.split("}")[2])
```

However, let me stress that this solution is 1) dangerous, because is very ad-hoc to the example page and might not work for other pages, 2) non-pythonic. You might want to play around a bit with the address elements in the page to come out with something better

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I have checked few other sites on the website, and they seem to follow similar layout, so your solution should do for now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix your problem 100%, but here's my solution

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as Open
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3"}
my_url = "https://www.otodom.pl/oferta/narozne-2-pokoje-nowa-inwestycja-0-ID43FH9.html"
req = Request(url=my_url, headers=headers) 
html = Open(req).read() 

page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")
texts = page_soup.findAll(text=True)

print(texts[91])
```

Comment: Many thanks for reply Riply - would you happen to know of a solution that could be more versatile and applicable to other links that may have more/fewer characters preceding the location?